# How can I start a new branch with squashed commits from an open PR?

Tags: git, github, terminal, rebase, cherry-pick

The problem: I have a PR with a tonne of commits. The branch name is also not accurate. I would like to start a new branch, and continue from the latest commit, without cherry picking each commit. I want all the work to be reduced to 1 commit that reflects its latest state.

I first tried rebasing, but the commits conflict with each other.

I then thought about cherry picking just the latest commit but I'm unsure of the syntax. (yes i read the docs but its not clear to me still).

I have checked out a new branch:

```
git checkout -b <new-branch>
```

then I tried:

```
git cherry pick <commit-sha> <branch-name>
```

The branch I want to 'correct' is an open PR.

This doesn't work as the terminal says "Unknown commit pick".

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: "This doesn't work as the terminal says "Unknown commit pick"" Because the command is `cherry-pick`, not `cherry pick`. Or just say `cherry` perhaps.

Comment: "The branch name is also not accurate" Why not just change it?

Comment: "I want all the work to be reduced to 1 commit that reflects its latest state" Why not just squash it all?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a PR with a tonne of commits. The branch name is also not accurate. I would like to start a new branch, and continue from the latest commit, without cherry picking each commit. I want all the work to be reduced to 1 commit that reflects its latest state.

1. Checkout your old branch.
2. Make a new branch and get on to it.
3. `reset --soft` to the first commit of the old branch (possibly even the commit that you branched "from") and make a commit.

Now your new branch "consists" of just that one commit, embodying the whole history of the old branch. Keep working. (You can withdraw the PR and delete the old branch if you like.)